# Are there soft line breaks supported in the chat?

Tags: support, chat, formatting

I know chat software that supports soft line breaks, these don't cause attention of you chat partner if a new section makes things much clearer. I tried some hot keys ([Ctrl]+[Enter], [Alt]+[Enter]) but they don't work.

In the SE chats, there is also the opportunity to star helpful postings, but if someone gives you a detailed explanation of a topic and formats it with hard line breaks you have to star each line. This seems not right to me.

Are soft line breaks supported at all?

....or did I only miss the FAQ/help centre article already explaining all this?

Comment: Try [Shift] + [Enter]

Comment: Great! Thanks :-) Where is is documented?